# How to call garbage collect on firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, memory, javascript, memory-leaks

I wonder if someone could guide me on some questions about GC on firefox.

1. Is possible to call the action performed when I click on the button `GC` using javascript?

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgoNx.png
2. on `about:config` there's an option `javascript.options.gc_delay.full`, is this option the same than clicking on the button `gc` on `about:memory`?

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimKW.png
3. I'm searching about of what of these enumerated options does, and found that:

   - Is the default amount of time to wait from the user being idle to starting a shrinking GC.
   - `javascript.options.gc_delay` ??
   - `javascript.options.gc_delay.full` ??

If someone knows the answer to these questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but is too long for Comment:

- Right-click on the GC button and select *Inpect element*.
- That opens the button properties, leading to the method called, doGC(), below.

  ```
  function doGC() {
    Services.obs.notifyObservers(null, "child-gc-request");
    Cu.forceGC();
    updateMainAndFooter(
      "Garbage collection completed",
      SHOW_TIMESTAMP,
      HIDE_FOOTER
    );
  }
  ```

To perform garbage collection, perform *Cu.forceGC*. This is [covered in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288922/best-way-to-control-firefox-via-webdriver). Hopefully, that can get you started.

Comment: Hi DrMoishe, tried to call `doGC()` and `Cu.forceGC()` but it returned as undefined, follow: https://i.imgur.com/BjYSW8N.png